# Why cant i get sender endpoint while using boost::asio::null_buffers?

Tags: c++, boost, udp

I want to read data from a udp socket asynchronously which is taken as a server socket and is listening on a certain port.

```
socket_->async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::null_buffers(),
    sender_endpoint_,
    boost::bind(&UdpSocketServer::HandleReceive, 
                shared_from_this(), 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
    )
);
```

the question is: sender_endpoint_ is always 0.0.0.0:0 while received some data from client.
when I use boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_) in place of boost::aiso::null_buffers(), the 
sender_endpoint_ comes right. I try to search this wired case in google, but cant figure it
 out. Since anybody encountered the case before? or anybody can help? thanks very much.

Comment: Interesting edge case. I haven't looked into this, but +1 for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to use null_buffers in such a way, yet.

The null_buffers type is only intended for use with `async_read/write_some()` on the "lowest layer", i.e. the socket or descriptor. It is not part of any of the stream type requirements, and so not supported by composed operations such as async_read.
[Please read this ticket for more information](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3627).

Given the tracker above the following may be transient, but the way the notifications behave now is that you get a (superfluous) `HandleReceive` notification with zero bytes received and an empty `sender_endpoint_` - a notification that you can discard, and then a subsequent `HandleReceive` notification with the correct endpoint information.

Comment: ***Note*** `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: [_"(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async\_wait() member functions.)"_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)